# PHP Session,Loggin Var, and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to figure out how to do this some the php file only loads once on loggin.

How could I do this?

Example: (that I came up with but not sure what to use).
Let say A=1 when the site loads up.  I log in and (if Global User is logged in and A=1 call or include welcome.php).

When the file is loaded the A=1 turns into variable of A=2 so that when I load the pages the welcome.php in this case will not load again.

On my logout page I need to set this value of A to be cleared of this session so A can be called to be 1 again after logout.

So, basically the file will only load once even if the pages are refreshed until user log out.
One more thing this is all done in smarty php using .tpl files.

Answer (score 0):

On your login page you can turn "A=1". Load welcome.php only when "A=1" and turn "A=NULL" when your welcome.php loads up.

Another case you can use cookie expiration. If you set cookie expire param to 0, your cookie destroyed after browser session shutdown.

Comment: I figured it out.  Created a cookie session that increases in session++ if user is logged in.  On logout page session destroy making values gone. If session = 2 then play welcome sound bit.